# Elasticsearch must some values and must not all others

Tags: arrays, node.js, elasticsearch, search

so I have an index with the following mapping:

```
{
"tests": {
    "mappings": {
        "test": {
            "properties": {
                "arr": {
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 documents with the following values for the field "arr":

1. `arr: [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 3}]`
2. `arr: [{name: 1}, {name: 2}, {name: 4}]`
3. `arr: [{name: 1}, {name: 2}]`

I would like to search in a way that I could find the documents in which all name values are in an array of name. However, the document doesn't need to have all the values of the array, and if it has one value that is not in the array, then the document is not good.

For example:

1. If my array of names is `[1,2]`, then I only want document 3, but I have all of them
2. If my array of names is `[1,2,3]`, then I want document 1 and 3, but I only have document 1 with `must` and all of them with `should`
3. If my array of names is `[1,2,4]`, then I want document 2 and 3, but I only have document 2 with `must` and all of them with `should`
4. If my array of names is `[1]`, then I want no document, but I have all of them

Here, the arrays are small, in my project the arrays in the documents are much more bigger and the array of comparison as well.

So, to be specific, I need to search in a way that:

1. All the names in the document are in the array of names
2. The document does not need to have ALL the values in the array of name

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have the control of your mapping like could you add an additional field? Just `one` to be precise.

Comment: Yes, I can do whatever I want with it :)

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer. Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Scripting (No Mapping Change)

No mapping changes are required to what you already have.

I've come up with the below script. I believe the core logic is in the script which I think is self-explanatory.

```
POST test_index_arr/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "filter": { 
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source" : """
              List myList = doc['arr.name'];
              int tempVal = myList.size();
              for(int i=0; i<params.ids.size(); i++){
                long temp = params.ids.get(i);
                if(myList.contains(temp))
                {
                  tempVal = tempVal - 1;
                }

                if(tempVal==0){
                  break;
                }
              }

              if(tempVal==0)
                return true;
              else
                return false;
            """,
            "lang"   : "painless",
            "params": {
              "ids": [1,2,4]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So what the scripting does is, it checks if a document has all its numbers in its `arr` present in the input, if so it would return the document.

In the above query, the part **`"ids": [1,2,4]`** acts as input. You need to add/remove/update values here this depending on your requirement.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a good solution, but for small arrays, with few elements in arrays. In your terms query, if I have a document with names `"1/4"` and want to make it work, I have to add `"1/4"` to the terms query. For small arrays it worked, but with more then 20 or 50 items in array and my documents, I have to do all the possibilities to make it work, is that really good?

Comment: @ArrowLightning Valid point. I've come up with another solution where no mapping changes are required. Could you please check and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I already thought about script before, I was wondering if there were other options but script works fine!